# Multiple complex string concatenations in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I need some help with this. I've already used `STUFF` and `FOR XML` to create the following result which is almost what I want. I just need to take it one step further so that I have 1 route for each pid.

So I have this SQL code:

```
select 
    pid, 
    STUFF((select ' ' + 
               right('00' + cast(direction as nvarchar(MAX)), 2) + ':' +
               + CAST(node_id AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
           from Path_Devices
           where (path_id = paths.path_id)
           group by path_id, node_id, node_index
           order by path_id, node_index
           FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('(./text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '') AS ROUTE
from 
    Path_Devices paths
join 
    Path p on p.id = paths.path_id
group by 
    path_id, pid, direction
```

which produces this:

[image]

I need one more concatenation on the ROUTE column to be performed so that my result set is 1 full route per pid, like this:

[image]

My preference is to have the whole result be produced by the database and not require any java processing at all on the back end. Also this will be part of a larger select statement which is created and passed using JdbcTemplate. The goal is to accomplish this without making any changes to the database or adding stored procedures. Just makes it all the more challenging. ;-)

So the question is how do I stack multiple concatenations of row string values to get the result that I want? Thanks in advance for any assistance on this!

Here are my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Path](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [direction] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [pid] [uniqueidentifier] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

set identity_insert Path ON
insert into Path (id, direction, pid) values 
    (1,0,'7E814659-1BE3-4941-9710-D78731E70E07'),
    (2,1,'7E814659-1BE3-4941-9710-D78731E70E07') ,
    (3,0,'67C8CB0D-8AFD-46E4-B06C-70EA19A949A3'),
    (4,1,'67C8CB0D-8AFD-46E4-B06C-70EA19A949A3'),
    (5,0,'9DADA1DD-F73C-4210-8DDD-A000ED1B9325'),
    (6,1,'9DADA1DD-F73C-4210-8DDD-A000ED1B9325'),
    (7,0,'BC2CF5D6-08EB-4530-B354-818039F24A8F'),
    (8,1,'BC2CF5D6-08EB-4530-B354-818039F24A8F'),
    (9,0,'BC2CF5D6-08EB-4530-B354-818039F24A8F'),
    (10,1,'BC2CF5D6-08EB-4530-B354-818039F24A8F')

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Path_Devices](
    [path_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [node_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [node_index] [int] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

insert into Path_Devices (path_id, node_id, node_index) values 
    (1,21,0),
    (1,2024,1),
    (1,2023,2),
    (1,2022,3),
    (1,2011,4),
    (2,2011,0),
    (2,2042,1),
    (2,2043,2),
    (2,2044,3),
    (2,41,4),
    (3,21,0),
    (3,2024,1),
    (3,2023,2),
    (3,2022,3),
    (3,2011,4),
    (4,2011,0),
    (4,2042,1),
    (4,2043,2),
    (4,2044,3),
    (4,41,4),
    (5,60,0),
    (5,2062,1),
    (5,2081,2),
    (6,2081,0),
    (6,2072,1),
    (6,2073,2),
    (6,70,3),
    (7,41,0),
    (7,2044,1),
    (8,2044,0),
    (8,3802,1),
    (9,3802,0),
    (9,2073,1),
    (9,2072,2),
    (9,2071,3 )
```

Using `SQL Server` 2012 or 2014.

Answer (score 0):

Which version are you using, the following is base on 2012+.

```
;with Path_Devices(pid,path_id,direction,node_id) AS (
    select 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa',1,0,21 union all
    select 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa',1,0,2024 union all
    select 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa',1,0,2023 union all
    select 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa',1,0,2022 union all
    select 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa',1,0,2021 union all
    select 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa',2,1,2011 union all
    select 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa',2,1,2042 union all
    select 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa',2,1,2043 union all
    select 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa',2,1,2044 union all
    select 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa',2,1,41 
  )
  /* your statement
  select 
    pid, 
    STUFF((select ' ' + 
               right('00' + cast(direction as nvarchar(MAX)), 2) + ':' +
               + CAST(node_id AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
           from Path_Devices
           where (path_id = paths.path_id)
           group by path_id,direction, node_id
           order by path_id
           FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('(./text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '') AS ROUTE
from Path_Devices paths
group by path_id, pid, direction
*/
  select 
    pid, 
    STUFF((select case when LAG(direction)over(partition by pid order by path_id,direction)=direction then ' ' else ',' end + 
               right('00' + cast(direction as nvarchar(MAX)), 2) + ':' +
               + CAST(node_id AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
           from Path_Devices
           where (pid = paths.pid)
           group by pid,path_id,direction, node_id
           order by path_id,direction
           FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('(./text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '') AS ROUTE
from Path_Devices paths
group by pid
```

```
+------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| pid              | ROUTE                                                                      |
+------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa | 0:21 00:2024 00:2023 00:2022 00:2021,01:2011 01:2042 01:2043 01:2044 01:41 |
+------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: We are developing for SQL Server 2014. Could you provide more explanation for the `With` part, please.

Comment: @Nelda.techspiress With just use for create testing data, It is LAG function only support up to 2012, I using LAG is for getting the direction of  previous row, If the current value is different with previous row, then use comma(,) replace blank.  [LAG] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql)

Comment: Thank-you. I'm getting binding errors on direction and pid.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
with cte as (
select 
    pid, 
    STUFF((select ' ' + 
               right('00' + cast(direction as nvarchar(MAX)), 2) + ':' +
               + CAST(node_id AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
           from Path_Devices
           where (path_id = paths.path_id)
           group by path_id, node_id, node_index
           order by path_id, node_index
           FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('(./text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '') AS ROUTE
from 
    Path_Devices paths
join 
    Path p on p.id = paths.path_id
group by 
    path_id, pid, direction
)
select Distinct
    pid, 
    STUFF((select ' ' + 
               b.route
           from cte b
           where (a.pid = b.pid)
           group by b.pid, b.route
           order by b.pid, b.route
           FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('(./text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '') AS ROUTE
from 
    cte A
```

Comment: I like this but it appears to have an infinite loop in it. I ran it for over 7 minutes with no result. If you other suggestions, please post more. Thank you!

Comment: This technique has some performance issues depends on the source. Please, provide the table structure and a sample data to others, and I help you better. And your SQL Server version